# How to create a OOTB Workflow Tasks List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am hearing about OOTB Workflow Tasks List, but I'm not being able to find any direct way to create a Workflow Tasks List (like a Tasks or a Project Tasks List). Is there any list definition for a Workflow Tasks list really?

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you trying to replace the task list that a workflow already is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Workflow Tasks list created in a Publishing site, is an OOTB Tasks list.

`http://mysharepoint.com/_layouts/new.aspx?FeatureId={00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107}&ListTemplate=107`

Here is the [code](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) from Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.ProvisioningHelper.CreateApprovalTaskList:

```
bool newListCreated = false;
list = ProvisioningHelper.AddList(
    lists, 
    "WorkflowTasks", 
    "$Resources:cmscore,ListNameWorkflowTasks;", 
    "$Resources:cmscore,ListDescriptionWorkflowTasks;", 
    WssFeatureIds.TasksList, 
    (Guid[]) null, 
    SPListTemplateType.Tasks, 
    out newListCreated);
if (newListCreated)
{
  list.EnableDeployWithDependentList = false;
  list.AllowDeletion = false;
  list.Update();
  ProvisioningHelper.DisableCrawlOnList(list);
}
```

Comment: Hey Rich, thanks for the reply, and apologies for my late reply, haven't logged in since a long time :(